# Group by date mysql and codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have table like this:

```
date_time               value
2015-06-20 10:00:00     10
2015-06-20 9:00:00      6
2015-06-21 6:00:00      5
2015-06-22 11:00:00     12
2015-06-22 10:00:00     11
2015-06-23 4:00:00      20
```

I want to get the total value of each date
Currently I have this on CodeIgniter but is not working:

```
$this->db->group_by('date_time');
$query = $this->db->get('table_a');
```

Any idea to fix. Thanks.

Comment: so what is Table a and what is table B?? upload your table code or structurer

Comment: don't mind other join tables.

Comment: give us your table structurer for **best solution**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ditch the star `'*'` and specify the expressions you want to return. To get a total, you need an aggregate function, and to get just the date portion of `date_time`, you can use the `DATE()` function.

```
   $this->db->select('DATE(a.date_time) AS date, SUM(a.value) AS total_value');
```

And you want to `GROUP BY DATE(a.date_time)`.

```
   $this->db->group_by('DATE(a.date_time)');
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$result = $query->result();
```

Try with add this line.